# How does glob() function work?

Tags: php, file, directory, glob

I know that `glob()` function is pretty slow but how does it work with the `GLOB_ONLYDIR` argument? Will it still check every file or it will use some index or whatever?

Comment: After looking at the source, [`ext/standard/dir.c:511-518`](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/dir.c#L511-518), you'll see that PHP still has to check each file to see if it's a directory. However I can't answer that because the question is now closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [the source](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/standard/dir.c#L511-529):

```
/* we need to do this everytime since GLOB_ONLYDIR does not guarantee that
 * all directories will be filtered. GNU libc documentation states the
 * following: 
 * If the information about the type of the file is easily available 
 * non-directories will be rejected but no extra work will be done to 
 * determine the information for each file. I.e., the caller must still be 
 * able to filter directories out. 
 */
if (flags & GLOB_ONLYDIR) {
    struct stat s;

    if (0 != VCWD_STAT(globbuf.gl_pathv[n], &s)) {
        continue;
    }

    if (S_IFDIR != (s.st_mode & S_IFMT)) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

So PHP has to check each file, regardless of whether it only asked for non-directory files.